# Internal drive is mounted as System Snapshot Mounted and all file manipulations ask for a password

Tags: macbook-pro, disk-utility, ssd

My Mac has spent like two weeks now with the System snapshot mounted drive. I can't save any file I can only copy files with each file asking for a password as if am working at the system files level; even if moving a file from Downloads to Desktop. I've tried to look up solutions yet people say it's normal. I can't even download files from Safari; it says I am low on disk space yet it's there. I can only download when I change to my external SSD. What can I do cause I don't want to format my drive?

MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015, macOS Big Sur)

[image: Screenshot of the Disk Utility window showing the Apple HD as a System Snapshot Mounted volume]

Comment: Does the boot process occur 'normally'? How much free space do you have (in Finder status bar, or "About This Mac".?

Comment: The boot process occur normally and the finder status bar shows i have 30GB free space